# Loading from Colab from specific folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to reveal only a specific folder from google Colab?
If I'm coding:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

then my entire google drive is revealed at the "files" sidebar, but when I'm trying

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/My Drive/Shared')
```

I'm getting an error:
`ValueError: Mountpoint must not contain a space.`

p.s. I've also tried to upload the files, but they get deleted after a while without activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can only mount the whole of your Google Drive files.

After that, you can create a symlink to a specific folder to make access to them easier.